# Spring SingleConnectionDataSource connection pool issue

Tags: java, spring

My application was running WebSphere where all the connection pool setting was done in WAS console data source and connection pool was handled by IBM WAS. but now i am removing the WAS server and moving to tomcat and using the below connection to connect with `Teradata`data source.  but getting below error. is there anything i am missing here? or what is properway to create data source using spring xml bean which manage the connections.

ERROR
 `org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection was closed in SingleConnectionDataSource. Check that user code checks shouldClose() before closing Connections, or set 'suppressClose' to 'true'`

CODE

````
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"/>
        <property name="url" >
            <util:constant static-field="MYCLASS._DB_HOST"/>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <util:constant static-field="MYCLASS._DB_USER"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <util:constant static-field="MYCLASS.DB_PWD"/>
        </property>
        <property name="suppressClose" value="true" />
    </bean>```
````

Comment: Try monitoring via wire shark to see what’s terminating the connection.

Comment: make sure that the bean defined here is a SingleConnectionDataSource